# Can't mount shared folder on Linux VM

Tags: mount, osx, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

**Host machine**: OS X El Capitan

**Virtual machine**: Linux Red Hat(64-bit) through Virtual Box

**Goal**: share folder on Mac, so when I change files on host machine, they will be changed on the virtual machine also.

**Error**: `mount error(13) permission denied.`

What I've already done and tried:

- I've shared folder on host machine: share with everyone with read-write permissions.
- I've run this command: `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.2/ia /var/www/apps/ia -o username="arsenpr",password="pass"`
- I've tried to put `sec=` option as other people suggested, also I've tried to delete parentheses around username and password.
- Also I assumed that I've used some other username(which was too odd, but gave it a try) - didn't work. I asked my terminal whoami and it answered 'arsenpr'

None of the above helped me.. I've spend 2 days trying different things, different flags and reading man mount.

Why I am not thinking about giving up is because it does work if I run the same virtual machine on Windows host machine and do exact the same thing. It worked just right away with the command in the second point, though I have domain name on my windows machine and I also added `,domain=DOMAINNAME` at the end of the command.

Actually I've also tried to put domain while doing it on Mac, but actually I'm not sure what it is and where to look. I looked at `System Preferences -> Network -> connected wifi -> advanced -> WINS -> workgroup`. But I'm not sure it's the right place to look for domain name of the network.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Ask any additional questions if I missed something. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Oh, here what I see today, after reinstalling the system:
[image]

It event didn't ask for password..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have a `centOS6` on Virtualbox I usually add in `/etc/rc.local`(guest machine side) a line like this :

```
mount -t vboxsf -o umask=0000,gid=48,uid=48 name-of-the-shared-folder /path/of/the/mounted/directory
```

this should mount the shared folder automatically at VM startup.

PS: if you have one you can get your current domain name by opening a terminal and perform eg. the following command:

```
domainname
```

UPDATE from Arseni Prokharchyk:

I should say, that without neok's answer this one didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which umask, gid and uid I take? Host's?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.. Nothing happened. I rebooted my VM and edited one of the files in the folder on host machine - it didn't change the file on the VM.. (

Comment: are guest additions properly installed?

Comment: Not sure, how to check this?

Comment: and why do I need this if it mount works on windows host? Thanks

Comment: I've installed guest additions.. didn't help. Actually it seems very odd to me..

Comment: as neok suggested, did you add the user ( the one(s) you use to access shared folder from centos ) to `vboxsf` group?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it a problem of permissions ?

On linux after creating a new OS through VB, I always need to add the current user to the vboxsf group in order to be able to mount the shared folder, please post the output of `groups $(whoami)` ...

To add yourself to vboxsf:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)
```

Comment: where should I run this command? VM? it says usermod: user arsenpr does not exist. $(whoami) on host machine tells 'arsenpr'. Thanks

Comment: The "Error: mount error(13) permission denied" is on linux (=guest) right ?
Then you should issue $(whoami) in a terminal in the guest ...
What is the command "groups" saying ?

Comment: It says root : root

Comment: Mmmh please do "cat /etc/passwd" and post the output: it's not advised to work as root, do you have a user account other than root ?

Comment: No, I can work only as root user.

Comment: The command you wrote gives pretty big output and I can't see it whole in the terminal.

Comment: IF you want to work with root: sudo usermod -aG vboxsf root

ELSE:
sudo useradd -d arsenpr;
sudo passwd arsenpr;
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf root;
logoff and login again with arsenpr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31938/discussion-between-neok-and-arseni-prokharchyk).